# Words associated with seeing beauty where it wasn't seen before

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for words (any part of speech) that are associated with seeing beauty in a thing where you had not previously seen it. The phrase "gain an appreciation" is sort of close, but (a) it's a phrase, not a word, and (b) I would like something stronger - having an "appreciation" for something doesn't necessarily mean that you find it beautiful.

Example sentences could be anything really, because I don't need this to be a specific part of speech. But I'll give it a shot:

"I **verb** the painting after seeing it many times."

"I have **noun** for the painting after seeing it many times."

"The painting is **adjective**. It takes many viewings to see its beauty."

"I see the painting **adverb** now after seeing it many times."

Or something which doesn't fit into any of these sentences is fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with using two words, [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1732?redirectedFrom=acquired%20taste#eid156162879) defines **acquired taste** as

> a liking gained gradually, through experience or repeated exposure; (hence) a person who or thing which is not immediately appealing, but which one comes to enjoy or appreciate over a period of time.
>
> Example: *1998   Time Out N.Y. 22 Jan. 91/4   Her..elliptical song structures are a bit of an **acquired taste**.*

To work this into one of your example sentences, you could write:

> *The painting is **an acquired taste**. It takes many viewings to see its beauty.*